# How to loop through value_counts in a dataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, extract, rows

I have a csv file which contains data of x, y, z coordinates with Temperature values. I have looped through value counts and extracted the rows of dataFrame for each value_counts.

1. But I want to get the rows extracted only which has values in value_counts greater than 20. I have the code below and also have attached the csv file.

I tried

```
a. df['x'].value_counts>20. This gives me only boolean value in values of value_counts
b. df['x'].value_counts().values>20. This gives me only an array of values greater than 20 with boolean values.

Currently I have,

df['x'].value_counts()

-0.00000    101
 0.00131    101
-0.00131    101
 0.00262     89
-0.00262     89
           ... 
-0.06202      2
-0.03805      2
 0.06050      2
 0.06545      1
-0.06545      1
Name: x, Length: 1493, dtype: int64
```

2. Once I loop through value_counts, I have extracted the dataFrame based on max temp value in each value_counts of x, the list of extracted values are appended in 'c' list. But this list contains header for each row which I am unable to remove it since it contains a list of dataframes. How can I remove this?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('slice0.03.csv')
df = df.round(decimals = 5)

a = []
c = []

for x in df['x'].value_counts().index:
  a.append(df[df['x'] == x])

for i in range(len(a)):
  c.append(a[i][a[i]['T'] == a[i]['T'].max()])

c[0:3]

[        x     y        z        T
 4635 -0.0  0.03  0.00131  33.9615,             x     y        z        T
 4636  0.00131  0.03  0.00131  33.9394,             x     y        z        T
 4632 -0.00131  0.03  0.00131  33.9418]
```

Data link for reference: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10_0MbXcP5iuI8rKn0LCHumuBqjJuPYd0/view?usp=sharing

Thanks and Regards,

Sunag R A.

Comment: What exactly is the header you are looking to remove? Is it the 4635,4636.... or the x,y,z on the top?

Comment: 1. Both 4635, and x, y, z, T on top.

Comment: it´s not clear what are you looking for. Please add a sample data and its desired output. @rasunag27

Comment: Both 4635, and x, y, z, T on top @Redvelvetpastry.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to get the values whose value_counts are >20.

```
bigger = df['x'].value_counts() > 20 # Gives you a series with boolean values
filtered_values = df['x'].value_counts().loc[bigger].index # array of values that have a count>20
```

2. Then you need to find the rows in your df that match those values:

```
filtered_df = df[df['x'].isin(filtered_values)] #Boolean indexing of rows that have an 'x' value in our list
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I do filtered_values after bigger, I am getting an error of "Too many indexers". How do I proceed with that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @rodrigomd. When I do filtered_values after bigger, I am getting an error of "Too many indexers". How do I proceed with that?

Comment: I made some mistakes in the original post, sorry about that. I have edited my answer now and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I am still a little unsure. Without modifying your previous code, you could add the following snippet at the end to help you get a list without the indexers:

```
c_without_indexers=[]

for element in c:
    for row in element.iterrows():
        temp=[]
        for col in element.columns:
            temp.append(element.loc[row[0]][col])
        c_without_indexers.append(temp)
```

c_without_indexers would contain the answer.